# How to change AppBar content using children widget?

Tags: widget, flutter, appbar

I am trying to change the AppBar title to "Log In" from LoginWidget level, but I don't know how to do this.

It may looks like IoC pattern, but I think it should still be possible to do.

I am now trying to extend a Scaffold object and add some methods to it, but it seems to not work.

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
            title: new Text("Application name")
        ),
        body: new LoginWidget()
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible

Widgets cannot modify other widgets in any way. The only thing they can do is submit events for them to potentially react to.

Only `MyApp` can change the appbar.

Comment: While I like when some things are impossible (as long as there are alternative solutions), isn't children able to set a state of it's parent that would rebuild the app bar? I am still new to Flutter and maybe I am missing something about state purpose. I like the Inverse of Control pattern, but if I can't use it in Flutter for making UI then it means that I will make a lot of new Scaffolds

Comment: That's not how you're supposed to design flutter widgets. If you want such behavior instead create a `LoginView` which instantiate a `Scaffold` with a custom appbar and `LoginWidget` as it's content.

Comment: Additional info : Flutter use composition as it's core. If you are in a situation where you need to write the same thing multiple times ; consider creating a custom widget which does that part.

Comment: I think it's possible by using InheritedWidget

Comment: `InheritedWidget` is the opposite. It's for `MyApp` to pass data to it's children.

Comment: An alternative would be to use `ParentDataWidget` for something similar to `Positioned` inside `Stack`. But that's overly complex for something like that

Comment: what about using Stream?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it may be possible to change the app bar by changing its viewmodel (assuming you're using something like Provider). The viewmodel sits above the Scaffold, which the appbar could reference for model values. If you can grab the model from the child widget, you can call a model method to update a property and call notifyListeners() to initiate a refresh.